# WPF Datagrid.Row AlternationIndex MultiTrigger Property and Viewmodel

Tags: wpf, properties, binding, multitrigger

I wonder why this doesn't works:

```
<DataGrid AlternationCount="2"...

<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <MultiTrigger>
           <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding IsTicket}" Value="False" />
           </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
           <MultiTrigger.Setters>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </MultiTrigger.Setters>
         </MultiTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

this code throws InvalidOperationException "Must have non-null value for 'Property'".
IsTiket is a property of Datacontext which Datagrid is binded to

This code works but I need MultiTrigger:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsTicket}" Value="True">
               <DataTrigger.Setters>
                  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gold" />
               </DataTrigger.Setters>
             </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

SOLUTION:
Syntax error, I have to use MultiDataTrigger:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
      <Style.Triggers>
         <MultiDataTrigger>
           <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
              <Condition Binding="{Binding AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
              <Condition Binding="{Binding IsTicket}" Value="False" />
           </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
           <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
         </MultiDataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Have you not set alternationcount? <DataGrid AlternationCount="2"

Comment: The specific property isn't somewhere in the error you get?

Comment: Yes the AlternationCount is set...

Comment: No specific property found in the error I got

Answer (score 0):

You're using a multitrigger rather than a multidatatrigger.
Try

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0" />
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsTicket}" Value="False" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```